# Python Sorting Text File From Highest To Lowest Based On Column Values

Tags: python, sorting

I have a very large text file that contains lines of data like:

```
('#DownWithAssad', '1')
('#DownYoTLParty', '1')
('#Download', '8')
('#Download:', '2')
('#Downloads', '2')
('#DownstairsMixtape', '1')
('#DowntonAbbey', '12')
('#DowntonAbbey?', '1')
('#DowntonPBS', '23')
('#Downtonabbey', '1')
('#DowntownAbbey', '1')
```

This may seem like a simple problem but I want to soft the data from highest to lowest so it looks like:

```
('#DowntonPBS', '23')
('#DowntonAbbey', '12')
('#Download', '8')
('#Download:', '2')
('#Downloads', '2')
('#DownstairsMixtape', '1')
('#DownWithAssad', '1')
('#DownYoTLParty', '1')
('#DowntonAbbey?', '1')
('#Downtonabbey', '1')
('#DowntownAbbey', '1')
```

I gather that I can eliminate the brackets () and split the data with:

```
import sys

f = open(sys.argv[1])
for line in f:
    line = str(line)[1 : -1]
    for sect in line.split(','):
        print sect
```

However I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse your text file quite easily using `ast.literal_eval`:

```
with open(datafile) as f:
    file_sorted = sorted((ast.literal_eval(x) for x in f),
                         key=lambda z:(int(z[1]),z[0]),
                         reverse=True)
```

How it works:

```
(ast.literal_eval(x) for x in f)  #turn each line in your file into a tuple
key=lambda z:(int(z[1]),z[0])     #function to determine how things are sorted.  Basically
                                  #sort as tuples:  `( int(z[1]),z[0] )`
reverse=True                      #descending order instead of ascending
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and thanks for the explanation, I was unclear as to what the key=lambda did but I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

This is along the lines of what you are trying to do. Note that parsing the lines this way is quite fragile (misformatted lines may break it)

```
from operator import itemgetter
import sys

result=[]
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = str(line.strip())[1: -1]
        sect1, sect2 = line.split(', ')
        sect1 = sect1[1: -1]
        sect2 = int(sect2[1: -1])
        result.append((sect1, sect2))

for line in sorted(result, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
    print line
```

Better ways to parse it would be to use `literal_eval` or regular expressions. Do you know if there is any special treatment when quote characters or commas appear in the strings?